# Prove $A$ is invertible given invertible matrices $B$, $A-I$ and $(A-I)^{-1}=(B-I)^\text T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove $A$ is invertible given $B$ and $A-I$ are invertible and $(A-I)^{-1}=(B-I)^\text T$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't even know where to start :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the only thing you really have: $(A-I)(B-I)^T=I$. Note that $(B-I)^T=B^T-I$ and start computing; somewhere along the way you should use that $B^T$ is invertible, since $B$ is invertible. The goal is to arrive at something like $A \cdot C =I$, where $C$ is made of $B$ and $I$. I can provide more details if you need.

Comment: ok I forgot I have $(B-I)^\text T=B^\text T-I$, thank you so much

Comment: Please thoroughly read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|141.7457).  The question reads like an exercise assigned to a student.  Nothing but a copy and paste.  That's a Problem Statement Question, and a question expecting someone here to oblige and "do their work for them."  Please refrain from obliging.